# RoR change format of date displayed from database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a row in my database that displays the date in the following format: `2012-04-26` . Say i take that value and store it in a variable `@date`. How can i change that format to say, 04-26-2012, or maybe even April 26th ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great snippet covering your problem: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2255

Example usage:

`<%= @date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") %>`

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't worry you, how ORM system serialize and deserialize date objects to and from database, and in what format they are stored there.

You only need to know how to convert your `Date` object into the string in the required format. It's where methods like [`strftime`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Date/strftime) and [other](http://apidock.com/ruby/Date)  can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a helper method so you can keep your views cleaner. Do it like this:

inside a helper file, ex. helpers/application_helper.rb

```
def formatted_date(date)
  date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
end
```

then in your view you simply do something like:

```
<%= formatted_date(@date) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails, you probably want to display the date or time in your views.
For that you can simply use the `localize` (or `l`) helper method. For example:

```
<%= l(@model.created_at) %>
```

Simply define the default format and any other formats you want in your locale file (e.g., `en.yml`):

```
time: 
  formats: 
    default: "%d %b %Y, %H:%M"
    date_only: "%d %b %Y"

date: 
  formats: 
    default: "%d %b %Y"
```

The format syntax is the same as format used for `strftime`.

Using a custom format:

```
<%= l(@model.created_at, :format => :date_only) %>
```